# TextView text and its drawable to the center of textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview with a drawableleft. As the textview is covering whole width of the screen so i want textview text and its drawable left to the center of the textview. At present only text is aligning to the center of it and drawable is always in the extreme left of it. So please suggest me something.

```
               <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cloud"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="@string/up"              
                />
```

Comment: Can you add the whole layout code?

Comment: It's called drawableLeft for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this using `drawableleft`. Use separate `Layout` with `ImageView` and `TextView` as shown below:

```
<RelativeLayout 
  //add necessary attributes
  android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView
 //Add your image here
/>

<TextView
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
          android:layout_weight="5"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
          android:text="@string/up" />

</RelativeLayout/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That I have done already but I was looking for a compact way to do this.